# ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Sass::Engine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compilation, rubygems, sass

I'm working on a legacy Rails 3.2.8 project and when running the project I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Sass::Engine
  (in /Users/sergiotapia/Documents/Work/foobar/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Foobar</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1845727542545946075_70110608859600'
]

  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (7.3ms)
```

My Gemfile looks like this and `bundle install` runs without any problems. I can also migrate my database perfectly:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'

  # Used by Twitter Bootstrap and/or Font Awesome
  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
  gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise' # Devise must be required before RailsAdmin
gem 'rails_admin', '0.4.3'
gem "cancan" # Allows us to disable Create and Delete actions for SiteSettings
gem "paperclip", "3.3.0" # Used for file uploads for ad Creatives
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'ruby-mysql'
gem 'useragent' # Allwos for easy detection of iOS devices
gem 'rmagick' # Dynamic e-carrd image generation
```

Why is Rails showing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I also run into this issue. I resolved it by:

- Taking 'sass-rails' out of the :assets group.
- Manually adding the 'sass' gem: `gem 'sass', '3.2.19'`
- I am also using 'bourbon', and in the process I had to also get it out from the :assets group and fix it to version 3.1.8.

The version of haml I am using is also 3.1.8.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a try by taking the `gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'` out of the `group :asset` block in the Gemfile.

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  # Used by Twitter Bootstrap and/or Font Awesome
  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
  gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
end

# Other gems
```

Comment: Tried this with the same result sorry to say.